# "Error: OID not increasing" with php snmpwalk

Tags: php, snmp

I am using PHP 5.3 and SNMP to perform a `snmpwalk` on a OID node that does not return in the correct order.  As a result, I get the error *"Error: OID not increasing"* and I cannot find a way to ignore this.

Alternatively, I thought I could perform a series of `snmpgetnext` commands to do the walk manually but I don't know to get the next OID value to issue the next getnext command on.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.snmp.php

Any advice on either solution will be a massive help.
Thanks.

The bash script for what I am trying to retrieve is:

`snmpwalk -c public -v 1 -Cc 10.3.1.42 1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.9`

The unordered results are:

```
iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.9.340550.15.15 = STRING: "Switch Name"
iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.9.29566.16.16 = STRING: "Switch Name"
iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.9.29486.17.17 = STRING: "Switch Name"
iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.9.101547.18.18 = STRING: "Switch Name"
iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.4.1.1.9.399668.19.19 = STRING: "Switch Name"
```

Comment: Have you captured network packets to see if this is an SNMP agent side issue?

Comment: I have executed snmpwalk with a bash script and it showed that OID values were not ordered.  I could ignore the default action of aborting when finding a decreasing OID value by using the -Cc switch.  Sadly I cannot find a way to do this with php.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** It looks like this might only be possible using PHP 5.4 or greater; the ability for the "getnext" family of functions to return the actual *OID* isn't introduced until then.

Part of the magic of the "getnext" functionality is that it gives you the *next* OID and *its* value.  However, you do need to coax PHP into giving it to you in a format that makes sense.  The intuitive method ends up giving you just the next OID's *value* and nothing else, which doesn't help.

First, however, you can use these options to make PHP return a more meaningful set of information.  In particular, we want the OID in its raw, numeric form.  In addition, we want an *object* to hold the value so that we can check the *type* of value that came back and handle it appropriately (for example, to distinguish between text, integers, counters, etc.):

```
// Note: Prior to PHP 5.4.0, SNMP_VALUE_OBJECT implied SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN. 
snmp_set_valueretrieval( SNMP_VALUE_OBJECT | SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN );
snmp_set_quick_print( 1 );
snmp_set_enum_print( 0 );
snmp_set_oid_output_format( SNMP_OID_OUTPUT_NUMERIC );
```

Basically, all of these together make it so that the output is *machine-readable*, as opposed to the fairly silly defaults.

With that out of the way, you can then ask PHP to get you the next OID:

```
$result = @snmp2_getnext( $ipAddress, $communityString, [ $oidString ] );
```

It is *very* important to note that the OID that you pass in ("$oidString") is passed in as the sole element of an array.  This causes PHP to return you an array back, where the *index* of that array is the *next OID*.  Because we told PHP that we want numeric output, we can then meaningfully read/parse this OID.

```
$nextOid = key( $result );
$nextValue = $result[ $nextOid ];
```

For example, you can try an OID of ".1.3.6.1" ("internet").  In that case, the *next* OID will probably be ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0" ("sysDescr.0") or some other OID (that is, whichever one is "next").  You can then take "$nextOid" and feed it back in until you're done.

Note that the *next* OID need not be "beneath" the original OID that you give it.  So, you may want to check to make sure that the OID that comes back is within the scope of the very first one that you gave it (if you're interested in an "snmpwalk" replacement).

In addition, since the OID comes back as text, you may want to use the natural sorting functions that PHP has to determine whether or not the next OID is "increasing".

Finally, remember that PHP uses different functions for the different versions of SNMP.  They did add an "SNMP" class that you can instantiate, but I haven't played much with that yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I get the error "snmp2_getnext() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given" which is confirmed by the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.snmp2-getnext.php)

Comment: You're right; it looks like they only added support arrays (the way that I outlined it) in 5.4: http://php.net/manual/en/snmp.getnext.php

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 5.3 you can use:

```
function snmprealwalk2($host, $community, $object_id){
    exec("snmpwalk -c ".$community." -v1 -Cc ".$host." ".$object_id, $snmpWalkReturn);
    foreach($snmpWalkReturn as $value){
            $oid = explode("=", $value);
            $walk[trim($oid[0])] = trim($oid[1]);
    }
    return $walk;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object version of NetSNMP has a flag to bypass the need of ordered OIDs.

```
<?php
  $dataSNMP = array();  
  $ipDevice = "10.206.4.38";

  $SNMP = new SNMP(1, $ipDevice, "public");
  $SNMP->oid_increasing_check = false;
  $dataSNMP = $SNMP->walk("1.3.6.1.4.1.14988.1.1.1.3.1.8");
  $SNMP->close();
?>
```

Using this, you will get all data without any warning. Only problem is that you need PHP >=5.4.0